# How do I begin to use rcy:nouislider in my Meteor Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, nouislider

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I've tried to google for the answer and can't find anything definitive.

I added the following package https://atmospherejs.com/rcy/nouislider

by entering the command `meteor add rcy:nouislider`

I am unsure if there any more steps from here. Do I need to import the package at the top of my JS file or can I go ahead and just start using it without any other steps?

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593154/meteor-how-to-initialize-nouislider-in-meteor/42593516?noredirect=1#comment72339777_42593516) and @jordanwillis answer was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Atmosphere packages should not need to be imported. The older packaging system did that for you, and the global variable 'noUiSlider' should be available to your code for you to use like in the documentation.

If you are interested, you can download the package code and see how it's put together. Just like a Meteor project there is client and server code. See here for more details: https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html