# Meteor: How to initialize noUiSlider in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, nouislider

The js code to initialize it is easy to find:

```
Template.templateOne.onRendered(function(){
  noUiSlider.create(document.getElementById('slider'), {
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100
    },
    start: 50
  });
});
```

Could someone just give me the corresponding html? I tried just a div with id='slider' and I tried copying all the divs from the example sites via Chrome's inspect function. Neither worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider).

```
meteor npm install --save nouislider
```

Create you slider container in your HTML file.

```
<template name="templateOne">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</template>
```

Then initialize it in your template's `onRendered` callback and be sure to input the package as well.

```
import noUiSlider from 'nouislider';

Template.templateOne.onRendered(function() {
   noUiSlider.create(this.$('#slider')[0], { 
     connect: "lower", 
     range: { min: 0, max: 100 }, 
     start: 50 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: when I drag the slider, it gives this error, any idea? Still works without problem: `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080`

Comment: Hmm...Not sure about that one. Have you tried googling it?